# What is a good reason to close "How do I find..." style questions

Tags: discussion

I just voted to close this question.  [Psychometric Test based on Deductive Reasoning and Orientation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93587/psychometric-test-based-on-deductive-reasoning-and-orientation)

The reason I gave was the "advice" one, but I'm not sure.  Is this a good reason, or is there a better one to list when we get these types of questions.

Comment: I've always been creating a custom one in those cases. Maybe we should create one similar to [stack overflow's recommendation close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Comment: Too broad / opinion-based presumably also applies.

Comment: Not directed towards anyone specifically: The linked question is not a bad question, it just doesn't belong here.  I am not sure why they piled on the down votes.  I am not sure if there is a good SE to refer them to for that but I would think when you have a quality question that just doesn't belong we would try to be more helpful.

This wasnt someone trying to get us to help him cheat, or wanting us to do it for them.

Answer (score 1):

## Off Topic

This question does not appear to be about the workplace within the scope defined in the help center.

you can either type in a custom reason or choose one of the predefined... it doesnt really matter as long as it is off topic.